# Android on softkeyboard display resize only one view

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I want to set view 2 under softkeyboard (view overlayed by softkeyboard) and make the screen resize adjustment for view1. When the softkeyboard is visible, I want to make the view1 scrollable by resizing the amount of area that has remained after the softkeyboard is displayed and keep the view2 at the same position as it was before and should be overlayed by the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Show us your work